# Multiplying two large numbers

Tags: c, largenumber, multiplication

I have this question that requires to multiply two large numbers . I thought  of adding the first number A , B times ( B is the second number) . I made the algorithm for adding two large numbers . so I thought this would work . the question is , would it  take a long time to do this algorithm ? , adding a number to itself a lot of times ?

Comment: Please show your work/trials...

Comment: Do you want to add or multiply? Your topic states it different then in your description.

Comment: @etalon11 His question clearly states that he wants to emulate multiplication as a series of additions.

Comment: What is wrong with simply multiplying them? Why must you add them repeatedly? If they overflow when multiplying, they will also overflow when adding.

Comment: Thanks erip, but I Do not really get the benefit of doing so...

Comment: Please define "large number" and "a long time".

Comment: I'm just asking if the run time for a series of additions would be big ?

Comment: Large as in it cant be stored as an integer . ( has more than 10 digits ) . and I can't use double . just int .

Comment: @user259548 It really depends on what you mean by "large".  If the numbers (both addends and sum) can be represented with 64 bits (i.e., if they are signed, then they should be less than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) then the sums (or multiplication) can be done *very* quickly using a modern ALU.  If not, then your algorithm's complexity can probably be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations.

Answer (score 2):

> the question is , would it take a long time to do this algorithm ? , adding a number to itself a lot of times ?

Yes. That's a very slow method of multiplying numbers as you need to to *a*  additions when you add *b* to itself *a* times. For better performance and still a reasonably simple algorithm, consider a shift-and-add procedure like this (multiplying *a* and *b*, putting the result in *q*):

1. *q* ← 0, *i* ← 0
2. **if** 2<sup>*i*</sup> > *a* **then return** *q*
3. **if** *a* & (1 ≪ *i*) **then** *q* ← *q* + (*b* ≪ *i*)
4. *i* ← *i* + 1
5. **goto** 2

Fast algorithms for this kind of problem are [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), [Toom-Cook multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) and [Schönhage-Strassen multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm).

Comment: you never increment `i`

Comment: @pat Now I do. Thank you for reminding me of this oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Check this algorithm:

```
long long multiply(long long a, long long b)
{
    if(a < b)
        swap(a, b);

    long long c = 0;

    for(int i = 0; (1ll << i) <= b; ++i)
    {
        if(((b >> i) & 1ll) == 1ll)
        {
            c += a << i;
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

It works in logarithmic speed of min(a, b).
If your numbers are really large, Fast Fourier Transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and Karatsuba algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) might help you.

Comment: Is `(1 << i)` computed as `long long`? Without a context or cast, `1` will be `int`

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, thank you, my bad. Code changed.

Comment: This code is not going to work: OP specifically says his numbers are too large to be stored in any integer type.

Comment: @FUZxxl Operation '+' and bitwise operators can be overloaded for (example) BigInteger class. I've posted this answer to show a nice simple idea of algorithm.

Comment: C does not have classes or overloading.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, i know. But main the goal of my post was to show an idea of fast multiplication without '*' operator, i think, author got it.

Comment: @Andreikkaa You describe the same algorithm I describe but artificially limit it to `long long` by spelling it out in C. I'm not sure why you felt the need to reiterate the content of another answer without adding anything useful.